# Wayland + Crash + Log File

Tags: gnome, log, gnome-session, wayland

I'm trying to track down a crash (or more accurately a hanging) of Wayland + Gnome on Ubuntu 16.04. I'm trying to find a wayland log file like I have for Xorg (e.g. `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`). So I can search for clues in my crash there. However I can't seem to find one. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Also is there a CTRL+ALT+DEL equivalent for Wayland that will kill it when it hangs?

Answer (score 0):

When i was troubleshooting my Wayland crashes i discovered within /var/log/syslog that it was gdm crashing on me.

i had the following log entries

```
Apr 27 08:59:46   /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4965]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): SDC (DFP-1): connected
Apr 27 08:59:46   /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4965]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): SDC (DFP-1): Internal DisplayPort
Apr 27 08:59:46   /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4965]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): SDC (DFP-1): 1440.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Apr 27 08:59:46   /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4965]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Apr 27 08:59:46   /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4965]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): LG Electronics LG ULTRAWIDE (DFP-0): connected
Apr 27 08:59:46   /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4965]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): LG Electronics LG ULTRAWIDE (DFP-0): Internal TMDS
Apr 27 08:59:46   /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4965]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): LG Electronics LG ULTRAWIDE (DFP-0): 600.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Apr 27 08:59:46   /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4965]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Apr 27 08:59:46   /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4965]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): SDC (DFP-1): connected
Apr 27 08:59:46   /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4965]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): SDC (DFP-1): Internal DisplayPort
Apr 27 08:59:46   /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4965]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): SDC (DFP-1): 1440.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Apr 27 08:59:46   /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4965]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Apr 27 08:59:46   /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4965]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: disconnected
Apr 27 08:59:46   /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4965]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: Internal DisplayPort
Apr 27 08:59:46   /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4965]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: 1440.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Apr 27 08:59:46   /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4965]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Apr 27 08:59:46   /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4965]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: disconnected
Apr 27 08:59:46   /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4965]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: Internal TMDS
Apr 27 08:59:46   /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4965]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: 330.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Apr 27 08:59:46   /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4965]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Apr 27 08:59:46   /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4965]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: disconnected
Apr 27 08:59:46   /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4965]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: Internal DisplayPort
Apr 27 08:59:46   /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4965]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: 1440.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Apr 27 08:59:46   /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4965]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Apr 27 08:59:46   /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4965]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-5: disconnected
Apr 27 08:59:46   /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4965]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-5: Internal TMDS
Apr 27 08:59:46   /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4965]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-5: 330.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Apr 27 08:59:46   /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4965]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Apr 27 08:59:46   /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4965]: (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "HDMI-0: nvidia-auto-select @2560x1080 +0+0 {ViewPortIn=2560x1080, ViewPortOut=2560x1080+0+0}"
Apr 27 08:59:50   /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4965]: (**) Option "fd" "38"
Apr 27 08:59:50   /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4965]: (**) Option "fd" "41"
Apr 27 08:59:50   /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4965]: (**) Option "fd" "42"
Apr 27 08:59:50   /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4965]: (**) Option "fd" "43"
Apr 27 08:59:50   /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4965]: (**) Option "fd" "44"
Apr 27 08:59:50   /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4965]: (**) Option "fd" "45"
Apr 27 08:59:50   /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4965]: (**) Option "fd" "46"
Apr 27 08:59:50   /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4965]: (**) Option "fd" "47"
Apr 27 08:59:50   /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4965]: (**) Option "fd" "45"
Apr 27 08:59:50   /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4965]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:67
Apr 27 08:59:50   /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4965]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:65
Apr 27 08:59:50   /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4965]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:68
Apr 27 08:59:50   /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4965]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:70
Apr 27 08:59:50   /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4965]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:71
Apr 27 08:59:50   /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4965]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:64
Apr 27 08:59:50   /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4965]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:72
Apr 27 08:59:50   /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4965]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:69
```

then i ran

```
apt-get remove gdm && apt-get install lightdm
```

This log entry from syslog was also written in my Xorg.0.log also

This is just a work around for me, i must have issues running Wayland on Geforce 1070GTX.

Comment: That's a great bit of data for finding out errors related to GDM+Wayland but is there a generic wayland log file?

Comment: I don't think I ever found one.